# Windows 10 Bluetooth connection does not work

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, mouse, bluetooth

I was working on one of my Arduino projects today, (currently just a bare Arduino board) and had it connected via USB to serial converter.
At a code upload, I've got a blue screen of death, and I haven't been able to revive any bluetooth device on my laptop since then. Which is not nice, having a bluetooth keyboard and mouse setup.
I have managed to unpair the devices, but at pairing, I can't see the brand and type of the keyboard and mouse (and anything else), which I had before, only the category of the device (phone, keyboard, mouse). File transfer from phone and to phone does not work either.

I have already tried troubleshooter, removig bluetooth device, removing the wireless adapter (which includes the bluetooth adapter too), removing drivers for both, restarting bluetooth support service, restarting the laptop, running windows update and also removing via command line. None of them made any difference.

I am out of ideas, do you have any? :(

Comment: When that happens, you must start from scratch, which means turning the devices off completely, remove the batteries if you can, forgetting the devices in Windows Settings, flush all known devices via PowerShell with the "btpair -u" command (admin mode, preferably; if you get an error message, install the BT command line tools from here (http://bluetoothinstaller.com/bluetooth-command-line-tools/), then try again), and you should be able to pair your devices again. Unpairing them just hides them from sight, but pairing settings aren't completely deleted unless your run the PS command.

Comment: The bluetooth module may have a hardware issue that caused the bluescreen - i would try to disable it in device manager and add an USB bluetooth dongle (cost: around 10 Euros).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately none of the above worked, but finally, problem solved. I have no idea what exactly fixed the issue, but here is what I did.

1) Delete all Bluetooth related register from

```
\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services
```

2) Make a dump of the deleted registers on my other notebook, which also has onboard Bluetooth.

3) Write the registry of my faulty notebook

4) Reboot

5) Cry from happiness

////////////////////////////////////////////////////
UPDATE: I ended up replacing the wireless adapter in my notebook, because after some time without any failure, the bluetooth option disappeared entirely.